# Failed to load native library: Couldn't load cardioDecider: findLibrary returned null

Tags: android, credit-card, card.io

Whenever i click on button to open camera to take pic of credit card, that time console displays this type of message "Failed to load native library: Couldn't load cardioDecider: findLibrary returned null", and in device i see this type of Toast Message : "this device can not use camera to read card numbers", is there any solution, please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: same question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868766/android-card-io-sdk-showing-this-device-can-not-use-camera-to-read-card-numbers

Comment: @Elior, please help me for this question

Comment: did you add the jar/lib files to your project? in which IDE are you using? netbeans or eclipse?

Comment: ya man, i added jar in my project's lib directory in eclipse.

Comment: @Elior hi, are you there?

Comment: can you post the logcat?

Answer (score 2):

This error is almost certainly the result of the `libs/*/*.so` native shared libraries not being part of your .apk. You can fix this by making sure that you unzip the library into your project directory and don't change the location of anything in the `libs` directory.

Also, be sure to note that by default it's `libs` (plural) not `lib`.